# I need to drop all rows duplicated with different index

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have a data frame like this:

```
import pandas as pd

d = {
    1: {'name': '1000', 1: 10, 2: 20, 3: 30},
    2: {'name': '1000', 1: 10, 2: 20, 3: 30},
    3: {'name': '2000', 1: 11, 2: 21, 3: 30},
    4: {'name': '6788', 1: 11, 2: 21, 3: 30},
    5: {'name': '0909', 1: 12, 2: 22, 3: 30},
    6: {'name': '3300', 1: 13, 2: 22, 3: 30},
    7: {'name': '4456', 1: 14,        3: 35},
    8: {'name': '9899',        2: 22, 3: 35},
}
df2=pd.DataFrame.from_dict(d).transpose().set_index('name')
df2
```

and the result df is:

```
            1    2   3
name              
1000       10   20  30    
1000       10   20  30    
2000       11   21  30    
6788       11   21  30    
0909       12   22  30
3300       13   22  30
4456       14  NaN  35
9899      NaN   22  35
```

I want to drop all duplicated rows which have different name, so I won't drop these rows

```
1000       10   20  30    
1000       10   20  30
```

because they have same name, but I want to drop these because they have different name (2000 and 6788)

```
2000       11   21  30    
6788       11   21  30
```

So the final df must be:

```
            1    2   3
name              
1000       10   20  30    
1000       10   20  30    
0909       12   22  30
3300       13   22  30
4456       14  NaN  35
9899      NaN   22  35
```

I have tried with

```
df2.drop_duplicates(keep=False)
```

but all duplicated rows are deleted, even the ones with same name. I don´'t know how to compare names in the process of dropping rows.

Answer (score 2):

So in your case

```
df2.reset_index(inplace=True)

df2[~df2.groupby([1,2,3]).name.transform('nunique').gt(1)]
Out[211]: 
   name    1    2   3
0  1000   10   20  30
1  1000   10   20  30
4  0909   12   22  30
5  3300   13   22  30
6  4456   14  NaN  35
7  9899  NaN   22  35
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, could you please explain me where you drop duplicated rows? Do you do that in .transform('nunique')

Comment: @NellyLouis `transform('nunique')` is to drop the duplicate